# Searching for a number with a wildcard using oData

Tags: javascript, sql, odata

I have a numeric SQL column that I'm wanting to search on but I'm not able to find an oData equivalent.

For example, in SQL I would use:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id LIKE '%123%'
```

I've tried the following for oData but no luck:

```
contains(Id,123)
contains(Id,'123')
```

The error I get is:

```
The query specified in the URI is not valid. No function signature for the function with name 'contains' matches the specified arguments.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use function `substringof`:

```
substringof('123',Id)
```

Comment: I believe substringof is depreciated and contains took its place. I get this error when using substringof: The query specified in the URI is not valid. An unknown function with name 'substringof' was found.

Comment: @n0kx Well, I only know `substringof` (for V2) and `contains` (for V3/4). The problem is probably that contains does not support number conversions... I suggest to check if conversions are available.